# Max efficiency iron farm in 96x96

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm playing Minecraft on a skyblock survival server. I'm looking for the best design for iron golem farming available in a 96x96 plot (**cannot** build outside of the dimensions). I've done some reading online and have done some thinking about the requirements.

1. There must be a minimum of 64 blocks between villages, so including holding cells and whatnot, can I build an iron farm in the corners of my sky block?
2. Can the corner based farms be stacked vertically? If so, assuming the build limit from about `y=4` being the bottom I'm willing to go, can they be stacked 3 high?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both of your questions.

You can create separate villages as long as there are 64 blocks apart in any dimension (horizontally or vertically).

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE04Ui90sQY) that showcases 4 villages in the corners of a vertical square. You should be able to fit 12 villages like this in your plot (in the 4 corners of the plot and 3 levels upwards).

Comment: Thanks for that! So is the 64 blocks from the outermost door to outermost door, or center to center or how is the distance between the villages measured?

Comment: The center is the centerpoint of all doors combined, and there must be 64 blocks between the two doors closest to each other between villages.

Comment: @JohnPugh The game measures the distance from center to center, BUT there should still be 64 blocks from the outermost door to outermost door. That is because there is a risk that the villages will merge when the chunks are unloaded and loaded again if two doors from different villages are less then 64 blocks apart.

Comment: Thanks for the info there. Would the 64 blocks also apply upwards as well? The 64 blocks from the top of one farm to the bottom of the other?

Comment: Yes, the distance is considered in any direction, including upwards (euclidean distance). You can also imagine a sphere around the village.